# Rails j render partial with locals

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I am attempting to render a partial using Ajax, where I send the relevant Javascript object to the partial using `locals`.  Unfortunately, I'm having trouble sending the object and I keep getting the error "undefined local variable".

**controller:**

```
class TransportationController < ApplicationController
    respond_to :html, :js, :json
```

**create.js.erb**

```
function getRates(){
    $.ajax( {
      ...
      (code cut out that's irrelevant to question, but this request succeeds)
      ...

      success: function( json ) {
        json.prices.forEach(function(price){
                $("#my_list").append("<%= j render :partial => 'my_item', :locals => {price: price} %>");
            });
            ....    
};
```

**_my_item.html.erb**:

```
    ....
        <h1><%= price.display_name %></h1>
    ....
```

**Error: (NameError - undefined local variable or method `price')**

Any help to sort this out would be greatly appreciated!  I thought I was doing it correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't pass the javascript variable to rails helper.

https://www.quora.com/Can-I-pass-a-JavaScript-variable-to-a-Rails-method

http://jing.io/t/pass-javascript-variables-to-rails-controller.html

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to define the html view inside Ajax success block ,you can have your .js file associated with the controller action which will render the partial html.Hope it will work for you.

Comment: Inside the Ajax function, I'm making a call to an external API, which is returning the data that I'm iterating over to render the partial. Is there a better way to go about that than putting it into the Ajax block?

Comment: It is suggested make that API call inside your controller action and call that action inside your Ajax call .Define all your variables  inside controller action and render the view.

Answer (score 0):

**create.js.erb**
You can change and add into this:

```
function getRates(){
    $.ajax( {
      ...
      (code cut out that's irrelevant to question, but this request succeeds)
      ...

      success: function( json ) {
        json.prices.forEach(function(price){
                $("#my_list").append("<%= j render :partial => 'my_item'");
                $("h1.price-display-name").last().text(price.display_name);
            });
            ....    
};
```

**_my_item.html.erb:** Add new attribute class

```
....
<h1 class="price-display-name"></h1>
....
```

Comment: Unfortunately I get the same eeror

Comment: May I know you `create` method? Have you put @price variable in this method. Then, try to use this `<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => 'my_item', :locals => {:price => @price}))`

Comment: The problem with that approach is that `price` is actually defined in my JS block (it's an element in a returned JSON hash), so I couldn't define it in the controller. My question is how to pass `price` into the partial right there as it's generated

Comment: I see. You can't set Javascript variable in tag rails as your price did. I will update my answer.

Comment: yes, this does indeed work and was what I had to begin with. The problem is that I have a pretty complex item to append (it's not just price.display_name), hence why I wanted to pass price through to a partial where I could do a lot more without it getting messy inside the JS code

Comment: Okay, can you share your full code in `def create` and create.js.erb? the good way to do that is making @price into the controller. Then, `@price` should be in a json format. Next, you can use in its partial file as you did right know.

Comment: Could you share `create` method?

Answer (score 0):

May be this could be the way

```
function getRates(){
  $.ajax( {
    ...
    (code cut out that's irrelevant to question, but this request succeeds)
    ...

    success: function( json ) {
      json.prices.forEach(function(price){
        $("#my_list").append("<%= escape_javascript render(:partial => 'my_item', :locals => {:price => price}) %>");
        });
        ....    
};
```